# Genexus - Mark unrecognized procedure parameters as ignorable in webservices

Tags: web-services, genexus

I have procedures that are exposed as Webservices (REST):

[image]

I need it to be able to parse the request body ignoring unrecognized fields (that are not specified
in "rules"). Right now, when procedures tries to parse something that is not defined within the parameters, they throw the following error:
[image]

**Example:**

Some procedure has the following definition:

`parm(in:&parm1, in:&parm2, out:&someResponse);`

Then we change to:

```
parm(in:&parm1, in:&parm2, in:&parm3, out:&someResponse);
```

The web service is updated on some distributions, but on some they're still on the old version with 2 in parameters.

The service that consumes these web services on different APP distributions are sending the body with the second (latest definition).

```
{
  "parm1" : "somevalue",
  "parm2" : "somevalue",
  "parm3" : "somevalue"
}
```

Unfortunately we don't have control of the third party that is consuming our web services, so in that case, it would be a lot easier if unused parameters could be ignored...

**USING GX 16 U11 - Java Generator**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way in GeneXus 16 to "catch" the request and do something previous to the object logic. In GeneXus 17 we have the new API object, there you can transform the parameters.

But, not everything is lost. Taking into account you're generating in Java, there is an "external way" to do it with [Filters](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html). I used them to log the client requests for debugging purposes.

If you don't want to mess with the code, there is also API Gateways you could put in front of your API services to redirect the requests to the right service. Bear in mind that I'm not a specialist in this topic, maybe a post in ServerFault would help.